# Segmentation fault only when debugging

Tags: c

im trying to make a code(incomplete) that takes a string and reverse the string inside of a parenthesis
foo(bar(zab))mlib = foo(barbaz)milb = foozabrabmilb
it works when i run it but Segmentation fault when im debugging it at the line
inputString[x] = inputString[i - index];
i try printing it no problem but when it reaches this line it says segmentation fauilt

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *solution(char *inputString)
{
    int parencount = 0;
    int thesiscount = 0;
    int size = strlen(inputString);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (inputString[i] == ')')
        {
            char tempchar;
            thesiscount++;
            for (int j = i; j != 0; j--)
            {
                if (inputString[j] == '(')
                {
                    for (int x = j + 1, index = 1; x < i - index; x++, index++)
                    {
                        tempchar = inputString[x];
                        printf("%d", i);
                        printf("%c", inputString[x]);
                        printf("%c", inputString[i - index]);

                        inputString[x] = inputString[i - index];
                        inputString[i - index] = tempchar;
                    }
                    printf("%s \n", inputString);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return inputString;
}

int main()
{
    char *text = solution("foo(bar)baz(blim)");
    printf("text = %s", text);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are passing a string literal to a function that wants to change the chars in it. This is illegal and undefined.

Comment: Crashes also outside of a debug build: https://godbolt.org/z/hh9n8cKGE

Comment: @mch It does not matter. It can also not crash at all. But it is still Undefined Behavioy

Comment: @0___________ I know, it's just that the title says it only segfaults in debug mode, therefore the comment that it also segfaults without it.

Comment: When `i` is 0, then `x` is 1 and `x < i - index` = `1 < 0 - 1` = `1 < -1` = false so the inner loop will not execute. You should refrain from writing loops as complex as possible and instead write them as simple as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a "char \*s" initialized with a string literal, but not "char s\[\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-char-s-initialized-with-a)

Answer (score 2):

You pass string literal and any attempt to modify it invokes undefined behavior.

You need to make a copy of the string before modifying:

```
char *solution(char *is)
{
    int parencount = 0;
    int thesiscount = 0;
    size_t size = strlen(inputString); 
    inputString = malloc(size + 1);
    strcpy(inputString, is);
 /* ... */
```